NextAuth 'State cookie was missing.' on first try, but succeeds on second
I've been spinning wheels on this for nearly 3 days now and I'm losing my mind:
Here's what happens. I click my Google OAuth sign on, get to the last step then I get an error. This is in my server error logs:
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error State cookie was missing. {
  error: Error [OAuthCallbackError]: State cookie was missing.
      at Object.use (/app/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:4:46997)
      at l (/app/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:4:43337)
      at async Object.c (/app/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:28:782)
      at async g (/app/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:4:26220)
      at async a (/app/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:28:19771)
      at async e.length.t (/app/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:28:21261)
      at async te.do (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.prod.js:18:17826)
      at async te.handle (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.prod.js:18:22492)
      at async doRender (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1455:42) {
    code: undefined
  },
  providerId: 'google',
  message: 'State cookie was missing.'
}

Sign In Error Screenshot
When I click the button from the screenshot and try the SAME email address I just tried, it works. I see the cookies being stored, and all works properly.
Dependencies:
next-auth@4.24.10
next@15.0.3

Things to consider:

This only happens in my production environment. On localhost, everything works fine when in development.
My setup is :
www.example.com:443 AWS ALB (https) => localhost:3000 NextJS (http)
I'm correctly forwarding the X-Forwarded-For header on my AWS ALB. I've tried both options Preserve, and Append. (Append is the correct one to use of course)
I've set both secure, trustedHost in the NextAuth: authOptions
I can hit my proxy and I see the headers. I see the state being stored on the cookies during the first run, but they aren't being passed as parameters for some reason to my server. I cannot find any settings that would cause this. Further, nothing makes sense was to why this would happen on the first time, but then not the second.

Other things I've already tried:

Env vars are setup correctly (e.g.: NEXTAUTH_URL=https://www.example.com)
I've removed all redirects in my code

My authOptions don't have any sensitive data so I can share it below if it helps other folks in the future:
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: "openid email profile",
          access_type: 'offline',
          prompt: 'consent',
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  debug: true,
  trustHost: true,
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // 30 days
  },
  jwt: {
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // 30 days
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account, user }) {
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
        token.idToken = account.id_token;
        token.refreshToken = account.refresh_token;
        token.email = user?.email;
        if (account.expires_at) {
          token.accessTokenExpires = account.expires_at * 1000; // Convert to milliseconds
        } else {
          token.accessTokenExpires = Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000; // Default to 1 hour if expires_at is missing
        }

        trackEvent("Logging in", { email: token.email });
      }

      if (token.accessTokenExpires && Date.now() < (token.accessTokenExpires as number)) {
        return token; // Token is still valid
      }

      return await refreshAccessToken(token);
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (session.user) {
        session.accessToken = token.accessToken as string;
        session.user.email = token.email as string;
        session.idToken = token.idToken as string;
      }

      if (token.error === "RefreshAccessTokenError") {
        signOut({ callbackUrl: "/" });
      }

      return session;
    },
  },
};

Does anyone have any other infrastructure or code suggestions? I've been hammering ChatGPT o1 and previously o1-preview for nearly 2 days with no resolution.
No one has answered any of the other versions of this question. Since my login works on the second try, my case might be different enough that it's worth keeping separate.
Thanks!
